# Android studio progress dialog not showing progress?

Tags: android-studio, progressdialog

I have the some code (full method included at the end), which includes a Progress dialog.
The problem is that the Progress dialog is not showing any progress (it is not moving from 0 to 100), it stays at zero with no movement until the code is complete and then it disappears. So it appears at the right time and is dismissed at the right time, but it doesn't show the progress in between.

Here is the section where I try to increment the dialog. The intProgress variable is working, I can see it incrementing from 0 to 100 in the log so why would that not show in the progress dialog?

```
                for(Animal animal : lstAnimals) {
                    i = i + 1;
                    animal.addToSqlLite(strTableName, animal, sqLiteDatabase);
                    int intProgress = (int) (((double) (i) / (double) lstAnimals.size()) * 100);
                    Log.d(TAG, "vvvv: " + "i = " + i + " total = " + lstAnimals.size() + " prog = " + intProgress);
                    progressDialog.setProgress(intProgress);
                }
```

Full method here:

```
    // fetches data from the server and copies it across to the sqlite database
public void fetchDataFromServerAndAddToSqlLite(ProgressBar progressBar, String strTableName, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, Context context) {

//        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Wildgoosechase");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading Animals...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(progressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.show();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.co.za/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        wildgoosechaseAPI myWildGooseChaseApi = retrofit.create(wildgoosechaseAPI.class);

        retrofit2.Call<List<Animal>> call = myWildGooseChaseApi.getAnimals();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Animal>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Animal>> call, Response<List<Animal>> response) {

                if(!response.isSuccessful()){
//                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

                List<Animal> lstAnimals = response.body();
                int i = 0;

                for(Animal animal : lstAnimals) {
                    i = i + 1;
                    animal.addToSqlLite(strTableName, animal, sqLiteDatabase);
                    int intProgress = (int) (((double) (i) / (double) lstAnimals.size()) * 100);
                    Log.d(TAG, "vvvv: " + "i = " + i + " total = " + lstAnimals.size() + " prog = " + intProgress);
                    progressDialog.setProgress(intProgress);
                }

//                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressDialog.dismiss();


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Animal>> call, Throwable t) {
//                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is missing of thraed  // thread is used to change the progress value

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            setProgressValue(progress + 1);
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

Comment: By the way there is third party library https://github.com/daimajia/NumberProgressBar

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work. I placed it in the method where I currently try to update the progress dialog. Is that correct?

Comment: This solution is simply wrong. Never update the UI from a non UI thread. See my answer for the correct way of using the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you David, I do agree that your solution seems logical, however, being a beginner, I am not sure how to implement it. I did post a reply to your answer asking for a bit more advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not call one function to do one thing

```
List<XXX> list;

public void fetchData() {
    //set start progressDialog

    fetchDataFromServer();
    saveDataToSQLite();
}


fetchDataFromServer() {
  ... 
  // Save response from server to list
}


public void saveDataToSQLite() {
  ...
  // Finish set progressDialog dimiss
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue could be that you're updating the progress bar from a non UI thread.
You could try to move the `setProgress` call into the UI thread:

(Assuming that your methods is inside an activity)

```
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
      progressDialog.setProgress(intProgress);
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I think it is something to do with the thread, I must admit I am a relative beginner and do not fully understand when I should be using different threads. Unfortunately, my code is in a separate class, but I do pass the activity through in the context variable. Is there any way I could use this variable to run on ui thread?